# Unable to read SPSS file from working directory

Tags: r, file, directory, dataset, spss

I have created a folder that has my dataset and set it as my working directory in Rstudio.

The dataset is an SPSS file which I named "Stats in R", I downloaded the packages foreign and Hmisc and tried to run to the following command to get the dataset:

```
data = read.csv("Stats in R.csv", header = TRUE)
```

…but the console showed the following message:

> Error in file.choose() : file choice cancelled.

The problem is, my dataset is in the working directory but whenever I try to open it, R shows me an empty folder. I run the `dir()` command and instead of getting the directory content in the console, I get the following message:

> character(0).

I really don't know what's the problem, the SPSS dataset is saved as a SAV file. I tried other extensions as well like CSV but nothing worked.  Any suggestions, please? I really need to sort out that issue soon. Thank you!

Comment: ```read.csv()``` reads ```csv``` files. Sounds like you should do something more like ```data <- foreign::read.spss("Stats_in_R.sav", to.data.frame=TRUE)``` (rename the file so it has no spaces in the file name.)

Comment: Another option is you use the [haven](https://haven.tidyverse.org/) package. I.e., `haven::read_sav()`

Comment: Andrew, thanks for that. I did as you said and it didn't work.. still facing the same problem.

Comment: As @xilliam noted, you have to read a .sav file in as a .sav file, and not tell R to expect a .csv. Try this `haven::read_sav("your_file_path/Stats in R.sav")` but substitute your `"your_file_path/Stats in R.sav"` with whatever your file path is. In Windows you can hold Shift while right clicking the file to "Copy as Path" then switch the backslashes to forward slashes. On a mac you can right click the file and hold Option key to copy it as a file path. You cannot tell R a .sav file is a .csv or .txt file. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that. I still receive the same error. "does not exist in current working directory". I am not sure whether the problem I am facing is in R or in the file per se?!

Comment: Could you please type ```getwd()``` into the console and confirm the current working directory? And could you type the exact file name with the extension in a comment? The extension should be .sav

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have some issue with your working directory - it's either not where you think it is, or you don't have full permissions and something is blocking the R Studio interface from accessing it.

Since you want to get this resolved quickly, the approach I would try is importing the file using the entire file path instead of the working directory, and then you can troubleshoot your WD when you have time.

This should work:

```
df <- read.csv("C://Users//Mina//Folder//Subfolder//Stats in R.csv", header = TRUE)
```